# linker claims library not found, strace shows it try to access valid path though

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, android-ndk, linker, shared-libraries

I am trying to cross-compile something for Android, so I am using a separate toolchain.  There is a library that the linker is complaining it cannot find:

```
arm-eabi-gcc: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin.so not found
```

The library definitely exists in this path:

```
$ ls -l /mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/libexec/gcc/arm-eabi/4.6.x-google
total 70053
-rwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout 47040814 Oct  3 14:29 cc1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout 50903764 Oct  3 14:29 cc1plus
-rwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout   423914 Oct  3 14:29 collect2
drwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout      204 Oct  3 14:29 install-tools
-rwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout     1090 Oct  3 14:29 libfunction_reordering_plugin.la
lrwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout       38 Oct  3 14:29 libfunction_reordering_plugin.so -> libfunction_reordering_plugin.so.0.0.0
lrwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout       38 Oct  3 14:29 libfunction_reordering_plugin.so.0 ->  libfunction_reordering_plugin.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout    89427 Oct  3 14:29 libfunction_reordering_plugin.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout      994 Oct  3 14:29 liblto_plugin.la
lrwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout       22 Oct  3 14:29 liblto_plugin.so -> liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0
lrwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout       22 Oct  3 14:29 liblto_plugin.so.0 -> liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout   238575 Oct  3 14:29 liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout 44647203 Oct  3 14:29 lto1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout   114284 Oct  3 14:29 lto-wrapper
```

So, in my compile line I included "-L/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/libexec/gcc/arm-eabi/4.6.x-google" and then specify "-lliblto_plugin" ... but I still continue to get this error.

Here is my entire line and error:

```
arm-eabi-gcc -o test \
-I/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/../android-ndk-r8b-linux/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include \
-I/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/../ported-deps/jni/libgcrypt/src \
-I/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/../ported-deps/jni/libgpg-error/src \
-I/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/system/core/include \
-I/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/hardware/libhardware/include \
-I/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/hardware/ril/include \
-I/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/dalvik/libnativehelper/include \
-I/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/frameworks/base/include \
-I/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/external/skia/include \
-I/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/out/target/product/generic/obj/include \
-I/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/bionic/libc/arch-arm/include \
-I/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/bionic/libc/include \
-I/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/bionic/libstdc++/include \
-I/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/bionic/libc/kernel/common \
-I/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/bionic/libc/kernel/arch-arm \
-I/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/bionic/libm/include \
-I/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/bionic/libm/include/arch/arm \
-I/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/bionic/libthread_db/include \
-I/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/bionic/libm/arm \
-I/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/bionic/libm \
-I/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libm_intermediates \
-D__ARM_ARCH_5__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5T__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5E__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__ -DANDROID -DSK_RELEASE -DNDEBUG \
-include /mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/system/core/include/arch/linux-arm/AndroidConfig.h \
-UDEBUG -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -mthumb-interwork \
-fpic -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fmessage-length=0 \
test.c \
-Bdynamic -Wl,-T,/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/arm-eabi/lib/ldscripts/armelf.x \
-Wl,-dynamic-linker,/system/bin/linker -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,nocopyreloc \
-Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-rpath-link=/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/../android-ndk-r8b-linux/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/lib \
-L/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/libexec/gcc/arm-eabi/4.6.x-google \
-L/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/../android-ndk-r8b-linux/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/lib \
-nostdlib /mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/../android-ndk-r8b-linux/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtend_android.o \
/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/../android-ndk-r8b-linux/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o \
/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.6.x-google/libgcc.a \
-lc -lliblto_plugin -lm
arm-eabi-gcc: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin.so not found
```

---

EDIT:  Running strace along with the compile, I see the accesses to read the shared library that fail:

```
access("/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-eabi/4.6.x-google/liblto_plugin.so", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/bin/../libexec/gcc/liblto_plugin.so", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.6.x-google/../../../../arm-eabi/bin/arm-eabi/4.6.x-google/liblto_plugin.so", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.6.x-google/../../../../arm-eabi/bin/liblto_plugin.so", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

But interestingly, the first path that it tries does in fact exist, but it is a link:

```
$ file /mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-eabi/4.6.x-google/liblto_plugin.so 
/mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-eabi/4.6.x-google/liblto_plugin.so: symbolic link to `liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0'
```

That link is also valid:

```
    $ ls -l /mnt/hgfs/Documents/thesis/android-wmon/core/os/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-eabi/4.6.x-google/
total 70053
-rwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout 47040814 Oct  3 14:29 cc1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout 50903764 Oct  3 14:29 cc1plus
-rwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout   423914 Oct  3 14:29 collect2
drwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout      204 Oct  3 14:29 install-tools
-rwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout     1090 Oct  3 14:29 libfunction_reordering_plugin.la
lrwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout       38 Oct  3 14:29 libfunction_reordering_plugin.so -> libfunction_reordering_plugin.so.0.0.0
lrwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout       38 Oct  3 14:29 libfunction_reordering_plugin.so.0 -> libfunction_reordering_plugin.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout    89427 Oct  3 14:29 libfunction_reordering_plugin.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout      994 Oct  3 14:29 liblto_plugin.la
lrwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout       22 Oct  3 14:29 liblto_plugin.so -> liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0
lrwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout       22 Oct  3 14:29 liblto_plugin.so.0 -> liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout   238575 Oct  3 14:29 liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout 44647203 Oct  3 14:29 lto1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 501 dialout   114284 Oct  3 14:29 lto-wrapper
```

---

ANOTHER EDIT:  If I go in to the directory containing the shared library and remove the link from liblto_plugin.so to liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0 and then "cp liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0 liblto_plugin.so" then it links properly and my program compiles.  Why is it broken when this file is a link?  (sorry, using "link" to refer to two different things here).

Answer (score 3):

It turns out this is a bug in using a shared directory across HGFS with my virtual machine.  If I pull the code off of a shared directory and in to the native file system, I do not get these build issues.

This was hinted to me on [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/compiler-fails-to-link-to-library-that-exists-strace-shows-no-such-file-though-4175430516/#post4797318)

Comment: Great find. Had the same issue with the Android NDK on a shared folder on the host used from a VM.